# Register ContentObserver in Application.OnCreate() VS Service

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I need my app to monitor (and parse) outgoing calls (among other things).

- There is a broadcast for that "NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" but it is fired when starting the call and I need to know when is it actually finished.
- For that I could create a `PhoneStateListener` and listen to "LISTEN_CALL_STATE" but it gets fired too soon again as the call is not yet inside the call log database. (I could launch a timer but.. beurk..)
- On last resort, I can put a `ContentObserver` on the CallLog URI (and get rid of the multiple calls) and detect the new entries.

That's actually how I'm trying to do (the third option), but for that I of course need to register my ContentObserver, hence the question : **where and when should I register it ?**

Apparently, the answer seems to be : within a `Service`..
But then when to start the service ?

- I need it on start of my application to catch up with missing entries, so I would need to start the service from all the "callable" activities... Here the app needs to be manually opened, could be a problem after a reboot.
- I need it whenever a new call is made : can be achieved with the `BroadcastListener` on "NEW_OUTGOING_CALL", starting the service if it's not already on. Get rid of the reboot problem here (as long as the app has been launched once and not user-killed since then)

But what would be wrong by registering them within the **`Application.OnCreate()`**  ?

- I already need to subclass the Application (or at least that's how I handled other things)
- from my understanding, the `Application.OnCreate()` is going to be called anyway either when one of my `Activity` is created (first time), or my `BroadcastReceiver` (after a reboot) starts the service, anything that needs my process to start...
- `Service` lives also as long as my process lives.
- I don't need an extra `Service` for that, don't have to bind, start etc...

So is there anything wrong registering ContentObserver in `Application.OnCreate()` or what would be the advantage of using a `Service` for that ?

**UPDATE :**

On the pro-service I'll just discovered that :

- If I want my application to start at boot_time, I listen to "BOOT_COMPLETED" with my `BroadcastReceiver` right ? So my process will be created, and I can register my `ContentObservers`... but then it will be quickly destroyed :

  `07-24 15:44:50.260: I/ActivityManager(531): No longer want com.test.test (pid 1829): empty #17`

That's because Android flagged it as a ["Level 5 : Empty process"](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). Why ? Because registering ContentObservers don't make my Process "not empty".
Starting a service on the other hand makes my process a "Level3 : Service process" and it won't get cleaned anymore (at least not right away..) so if later on I launch the app, the process is already here, quietly listening...

Comment: I am facing similar problem,Did you found any solution,specifically where to unregister ContentObserver?